# I just received an .aspx.cs file...how do I run it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I was tasked with coming up with a way to automatically send an email on a .NET server, and was given a snippet of code to work with:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace SendMailSample
{
    public partial class SendMailSample : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void btSendMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
            mailMsg.To.Add("test@example.com");
            mailMsg.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@example.com");
            //Set subject and body
            mailMsg.Subject = "[Subject]";
            mailMsg.Body = "[Body]";
            //Set mail server and port
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("localhost", 25);
            SmtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
        }
   }
}
```

And I have no idea how to run it. I have IIS 7 installed (on Win7) with ASP.NET feature (from Add/Remove Programs). I tried navigating to the file directly (since I'm used to PHP) and got a 404 error. I added an empty web.config file and edited permissions on the aspx.cs file and the .config file to include IUSR and I'm still getting 401 unauthorized error.

What's the fastest way to run an aspx.cs file?

EDIT: Would just like to add that I don't have access to Visual Studio. I would like to just have the .NET process take the file and run it, as much like PHP as possible, since that is what I am used to.

Comment: The conventional way would be to create a project in visual studio and paste this code into a codebehind then run it

Comment: Read about the code behind model here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/015103yb%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX

Comment: Just edited, I don't have access to Visual Studio or the ability to install it.

Comment: Is there a way to just run a codebehind file on its own, without a matching aspx html page? Such as from a javascript ajax call?

Comment: @Esaevian If you can't install VS then you're pretty much screwed

Comment: @DGibbs I'll try again. I downloaded the installer from asp.net/downloads and it downloaded the files, but has been stuck on "Installing Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web" for about an hour. I need a solution soon, so I can't really just sit around twiddling my thumbs waiting for it to install. Was hoping there was a way around it.

Comment: @Esaevian The web installer is pretty slow, I would download the ISO instead. Also, check the system requirements to be sure that you meet them. Failing that, you can try an older version of VS.

Comment: @DGibbs Well, the download isn't the problem, it's the install. I imagine it would still take forever even with the ISO, no? What I wouldn't give to get back to coding in Notepad and throwing it up on a server and it just works.

Comment: "Is there a way to just run a codebehind file on its own, without a matching aspx html page? Such as from a javascript ajax call?" - Unlike most PHP, C# needs to be compiled (which is why C# is normally so much faster).

Comment: You don't need Visual Studio nor use the command line compiler to get this working. See bastos.sergio answer below. The Compilation happens automatically when the page is first opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run an aspx.cs file... This is by design, as files with a .cs extension must be compiled...

What you can do is create an .aspx file and copy that method to it, so that it can run without you having to generate a dll... The compilation still happens, but it happens in a transparent way--You don't have to deal with the dll...

Something like (*following code was not tested*):

```
<!-- directives -->
<% @Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.Mail" %>

<!-- code section -->
<script runat="server">
protected void btSendMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
    mailMsg.To.Add("test@example.com");
    mailMsg.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@example.com");
    //Set subject and body
    mailMsg.Subject = "[Subject]";
    mailMsg.Body = "[Body]";
    //Set mail server and port
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("localhost", 25);
    SmtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
}
</script>

<!-- Layout -->
<html>
<head> <title> Test </title> </head>
<body>
<h3> Test </h3>
<form runat="server">
    <input runat="server" id="button1" type="submit" 
    value="Enter..." OnServerClick="btSendMail_Click"/>
<hr />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I imagine doing something like $("#button1").click() in jquery would trigger the function? That sounds pretty good. I would just have to convert my current .html page to .aspx and add this in. For neatness, is there a way to keep the C# code outside of the inital file...like `<script runat=server src=email.aspx.cs></script>` ?

Comment: As for your other question, yes you can keep out the C# code out of the aspx file... (that's what aspx.cs files are for) :)

Answer (score 2):

What you were sent is a C# source file which was associated with an ASP.Net Web page.  You won't be able to run this directly as if it were some sort of executable or interpreted script.  The person who sent it to you presumes you know how to code in C# and that you would be referencing this for an example of how to use the SmtpClient class.

=== EDIT ===

As this particular class contains a code-behind with an event handler for a send mail button, it won't be that useful to you aside from as an example.  If you'd like to create an application based on this example, however, you'll need to obtain a C# IDE (Visual Studio, SharpDevelop, Mono, etc.), or you can use a C# compiler directly from the command line.

Comment: I do know C#, I just don't have the environment. Seems like there's no way to get the environment without Visual Studio (not even command line?). Maybe I'm just too used to LAMP.

Comment: My apologies for assuming you didn't know C#.  While it is possible to learn the C# language through other means (LinqPad, CS-Script, etc.), the vast majority of people who program in C# come by their knowledge using Visual Studio or some other IDE such as SharpDevelop.  Your question presumed you could "run" the file as if it were an executable or script file, so my assumption is that you haven't had that much exposure to any .Net development environment.  It is possible to compile a class from the command line, however, using either Microsoft's CSC.exe compiler or Mono.

Comment: No worries. I don't have *intimate* knowledge of C#, and probably don't know most of the base stuff for .NET development. Most of my exposure has been with Unity game development, but with a bit of lower level stuff that got me deeper than the abstraction level Unity provides.

Comment: Basically you were sent a C# file that needs to be coupled with another HTML-ish (.aspx) file. The C# file needs to be compiled like an executable program, the ASP.NET server then run's the compiled .dll when HTML-ish file needs it.

Answer (score 2):

> EDIT: Would just like to add that I don't have access to Visual Studio. I would like to just have the .NET process take the file and run it, as much like PHP as possible, since that is what I am used to.

That's not going to happen. You're not working with an interpreted language. The code needs compiled because this is a standard web form with code behind. You need to [download the express version of Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-express-web) for web development, create a new Web Forms project, and move this code into the `Default.aspx`.

At that point you can just hit <kbd>F5</kbd> in the IDE and the application will run.

Answer (score 0):

The code you were given is from the codebehind of an ASPX page. More specifically it's the method that's triggered when a button is pushed. I would 1) create a new webform in Visual Studio. 2) create a button on that page. 3) double click the new button to get to the codebhind. 4) paste the code you were given into the new onclick even for the new button.

Paste this code into the new onclick method:

```
MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
mailMsg.To.Add("test@example.com");
mailMsg.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@example.com");
//Set subject and body
mailMsg.Subject = "[Subject]";
mailMsg.Body = "[Body]";
//Set mail server and port
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("localhost", 25);
SmtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
```

**Edit:**

You can use AJAX, sure but you'll still need the front part of your missing codebehind. You can create an html form page and use the JQuery from below on your buttons onclick event. Like I said, be sure to construct the front-end of your aspx page and name it: "YourASPXPage.aspx"

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "YourASPXPage.aspx",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something 
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to get this form functionality via ajax without a Visual Studio created webform? (the page I am building the email would be sent when you click an image displayed on an HTML5 canvas)

Comment: Why did you answer twice?  The customary response would be to edit your original post with a more complete answer.